# Error not being caught (AsyncCallback)

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asynchronous, error-handling

Hi there i have a piece of code which connects using sockets to a server

```
Try
    'Connect To The Server
    Dim socketclient As New TcpClient
    Dim success
    Dim result
    result = socketclient.BeginConnect(ip, port, socket.EndConnect, socketclient)
    success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000, True)
    If socketclient.Connected = False Then
        Throw New Exception("Server is offline")
    End If
catch ex as exception

End Try
```

As you can see. if a server is offline, my try-catch setup doesn't catch the error "host is unknown" i believe this is because the error occurs during the async call. IF this is true, how does one catch an error in an async call?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You should end the async operation.
Your wait is totally unnecessary, if you just want to block waiting for the connection just call EndConnect over the socket ;) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect.aspx